# How to get the list of documents contained in a whole sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, content

I work on a sharepoint containing pleinty of libraries.
I receive every day an automatic email listing all the activities that happened the day before (document added, modified, deleted).
I can see that sometimes this automatic email is truncated (bugged) : only a few lines appear whereas I know that other documents have been added.
Is there a place directly in the sharepoint to retrieve the activity ?
Is there also a way to get the list of all documents contained in the whole sharepoint (not just in one library) ?

thanks in advance if you can help.
Caroline

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? You can get all documents by configuring search on document content type

Comment: SharePoint online or SharePoint Server? Please only tag with what you're actually using, because these are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The emails you mention seems to be the Alerts. The alerts needs to be set on libraries or lists before it can send notification Email mentioning the change made. For more information about it, check the official introduction [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918).

May I know what version of SharePoint are you using? Mostly it will be done more easily via PowerShell.

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise(like SharePoint 2013, 2016, 2019), please try the script [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-detail-report-of-all-b29ea8e2).

For SharePoint Online, please try the script [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-all-documents-using-powershell.html)